# Log in to .aspx web form and view http response

Tags: c#, asp.net

There is a website with a .aspx page that contains a log in form.

I would like to log in to this website with my credentials and retrieve the http response and print it out in a console.

I have done the same with a standard html form containing a POST, but there is no POST in this pages source. I'm unsure how to proceed.

Here is the login forms source:

```
<td width="370" class="loginScreenBox">
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
                        <tr>
                        <td class="heading" colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
                            Existing Partner
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: right;">
                            Enter group reference number:
                        </td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="_ctl1:userName" type="text" id="_ctl1_userName" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: right;">
                            Password:
                        </td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="_ctl1:passWord" type="password" id="_ctl1_passWord" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center; padding-bottom: 15px;">
                            <input type="submit" name="_ctl1:btnLogin" value="Login" id="_ctl1_btnLogin" class="btn" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
</td>
```

The website is http://hoteladmin.laterooms.com/en/SignIn.aspx?&ReturnUrl=%2fmain.aspx

Comment: Can you post the full page?

Comment: If you do a view source on that page you can see exactly where it is attempting to post the login info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Updated) Tested with your URL and am getting back a login denied (credentials which I don't have :)) So it definitely is working:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://hoteladmin.laterooms.com/en/SignIn.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fmain.aspx");
var container = new CookieContainer();
//
request.CookieContainer = container;
//
var response = request.GetResponse();


var bufferIntitial = new byte[512];
string responseTextInitial = "";
using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    while (responseStream.Read(bufferIntitial, 0, 512) > 0)
    {
        responseTextInitial += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bufferIntitial);
    }
}

/// NEW REQUEST

var loginRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://hoteladmin.laterooms.com/en/SignIn.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fmain.aspx");
// Resuse the cookie container containing the cookies received from our initial request.
loginRequest.CookieContainer = container;

var requestFormData = new StringBuilder();
requestFormData.Append("__VIEWSTATE=" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(ExtractViewState(responseTextInitial)) + "&");
requestFormData.Append("_ctl1:userName=" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("user123") + "&");
requestFormData.Append("_ctl1:userPass=" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("pass123") + "&");
requestFormData.Append("_ctl1:btnLogin=" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Login"));

var requestFormDataByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestFormData.ToString());

loginRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.57 Safari/537.36";
loginRequest.Method = "POST";
loginRequest.ContentLength = requestFormDataByte.Length;
loginRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

using (var requestStream = loginRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(requestFormDataByte, 0, requestFormDataByte.Length);
}

var loginResponse = loginRequest.GetResponse();

var buffer = new byte[512];
string responseText = "";
using (var responseStream = loginResponse.GetResponseStream())
{
    while (responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, 512) > 0)
    {
        responseText += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
    }
}
```

Helper function :

```
private static string ExtractViewState(string s)
{
    string viewStateNameDelimiter = "__VIEWSTATE";
    string valueDelimiter = "value=\"";

    int viewStateNamePosition = s.IndexOf(viewStateNameDelimiter);
    int viewStateValuePosition = s.IndexOf(valueDelimiter, viewStateNamePosition);

    int viewStateStartPosition = viewStateValuePosition + valueDelimiter.Length;
    int viewStateEndPosition = s.IndexOf("\"", viewStateStartPosition);

    return s.Substring(viewStateStartPosition, viewStateEndPosition - viewStateStartPosition);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer f0x. Unfortunately I tried this on the site and it just returns the same login page.
I've uploaded my question with a link to the page in question, if you have a few minutes I would really appreciate any help.
Of course, I have entered the appropriate username and password and URL into your code.

Comment: @user2018084:  You likely need to preserve any cookies and/or the __VIEWSTATE values as well.  In other words, first request the page, grab any cookies/viewstate and submit that information back along with your form fields.

Comment: @user2018084 - Please have a look at the edit above, it can be cleaned up a lot but you get the idea what Chris was talking about.